# Some contacts are missing in Experience Profile (IndexWorker error)

Tags: solr, indexing, experience-profile

We have **Sitecore 9.1** with **Solr-7.2.1** environment. Some contacts in our solution are missing in *Experience Profile*. All of these contacts are **known** and have a lot of **webvisits**.

And everything is OK when I open contact by direct link like (no errors in logs):
*/sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceProfile/contact?cid=608BD993-34A6-0000-0000-05B12000A4AC*

After investigation I found an weird error in **IndexWorker** log that appears when I reload *Experience Profile*:

```
System.FormatException: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
   at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
   at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Serialization.XObjectReader.ReadPrimitive(JsonReader reader, XdbPrimitiveTypeKind typeKind)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Serialization.XObjectReader.ReadXObject(XdbType expectedType)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonParseExtensions.ToXObject(JObject jobject, XdbModel model, XdbType expectedType)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrResults.JsonParseExtensions.ToXObject(JObject jobject, XdbModel model, EntityType entityType, String facetKey)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.DataRecordMapper.CreateFacetPropertyWithLastModified(KeyValuePair`2 facet)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.<ConcatIterator>d__59`1.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.DataRecordMapper.<ConvertToXObjects>d__30.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.JObjectExpansion.JObjectPropertiesExpander.Expand(IEnumerable`1 properties)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.DataRecordMapper.<MapObjects>b__13_0(DataRecord objectToIndex)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.JsonPostCreator.CreateUpdateBatchJson(IEnumerable`1 docsToAdd)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.JsonPostCreator.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<CreateBatchUpdatePosts>b__0(IReadOnlyCollection`1 b)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.ParallelProcessing[T](IEnumerable`1 dataToProcess, Func`3 asyncFunc, SemaphoreSlim throttle, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.SendJsonPostsToSolr(Uri updateUri, IEnumerable`1 jsonPosts, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.<Write>b__0()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.<Write>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexWriterCountersDecorator.<Write>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.Indexer.<IndexSingleSetAbortingOnSyncWriteFailures>d__15.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.AsyncForeachExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`2.<<GetRunActionWithCancelOnFailure>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.AsyncForeachExtensions.<ParallelAsyncForeach>d__4`2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.AsyncForeachExtensions.<ParallelAsyncForeach>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.IndexerExtensions.<IndexNextChangesSimple>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.SingleThreadedIndexer.<IndexNextChangesWithTiming>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Indexing.SingleThreadedIndexer.<RunInThread>d__6.MoveNext()
```

As I understand from this error, it failed when try to parse some contact facet property. But I don`t even have custom facets, I use only default ones:

- PersonalInformation
- EmailAddress
- PhoneNumber
- Avatar

Has anybody faced this problem? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the xdb index? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuilding-the-xdb-search-index.html

Comment: @MarkLowe, yes, the same error appears while rebuilding: "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string" at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriter.SendJsonPostsToSolr. It seems that it can`t parse some facet property, but I have no idea what property, all of them look fine in Shard database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After investigating I found that this error occured in **Avatar** facet.

It looks like sitecore indexer bug.

This issue happens when image for avatar has a big/medium resolution. Image data (*byte[]*) is big and as I understand there are some limits in *JsonReader* or somewhere else.

After many attempts I found that **128x128** jpeg image is OK and error dissappears, but **256x256** jpeg image still produced this issue (original resolution in *Experience Profile* is **170x170**).

So I just add a code snippet that resize avatar image before saving to xconnect facet.

This is my helper:

```
public static class ImageHelper
{
    public static byte[] ResizeToJpeg(Stream stream, int width, int height, long qualityPercent)
    {
        Image img = Image.FromStream(stream);
        var bitmap = ResizeImage(img, width, height);
        return Compress(bitmap, qualityPercent);
    }

    private static Bitmap ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
    {
        var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
        var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

        destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.Default;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Default;
            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.Default;
            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.Default;

            using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
            {
                wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);
                graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
            }
        }

        return destImage;
    }

    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static byte[] Compress(Bitmap bitmap, long qualityPercent)
    {
            var jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

            var myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

            var myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, qualityPercent);
            myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);

            return memoryStream.ToArray();

    }
}
```

And an example how I use it:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);

var resizedImageBytes = ImageHelper.ResizeToJpeg(stream, 128, 128, 50L);

Avatar avatar = new Avatar(resizedImageBytes, "image/jpeg");
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, thats good to know! I've never used the avatar facet so far.

Comment: Yes, we used Avatar facet many times and never fased this issue (in sitecore 8 it seems have and  no limits). But in this project we allowed our customers to take photo from theirs webcam (as alternative to uploading) and because of this this issue is reproduced only for particular contacts.

Comment: Another workaround for this issue is to remove the avatar facet from the copy of the model the indexer has. This has the added benefit that the indexer no longer even reads this facet, which is good as there is not much value of indexing it.

Comment: @eglasius it can be a good way too, could you explain where and how to do it?